# OData request without part of composite primary key in url

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, odata

I'm writing an application using EF6 Code First, and exposing my entities via OData endpoints. I have what is essentially a change tracking entity that keeps track of all previous values of another entity; something similar to the following:

```
public class QuizAnswerHistory
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string AnswerValue { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `QuizAnswer` entity, which has exactly the same properties, except it's composite primary key doesn't include `ModifiedDate`. It references only a `Student` entity, and a `Question` entity.

Now, because I want to be able to get the entire `QuizAnswerHistory` entity for a specific `Student/Question`, I don't want to have to specify the `ModifiedDate` in my OData request.

However, because the `ModifiedDate` is a primary key, when I send a GET request to `/odata/QuizAnswerHistory(StudentId=1,QuestionId=2)`, I get the error, **"The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity."**

Is it possible to keep the `ModifiedDate` as a primary key, but not require it in my requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options to resolve the issue:

1. Send a GET request to this URL:
   /odata/QuizAnswerHistory?$filter=StudentId eq 1 and QuestionId eq 2
2. Using OData Function feature, but you need to upgrade from OData v3 to v4, where DateTime type is replace with DateTimeOffset. For Function sample, please refer:https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/

Comment: I was so focused on my composite key, that I completely forgot about the filter option. Perfect, thanks!